# Can any one explain why StreamWriter is an Unmanaged Resource.

Tags: c#, system.io.file, unmanagedresources

Want to understand what part of StreamWriter source code is Unmanaged code. Have went through the code in [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,937fd0aec8b19a3a) website.

But it seems to be complex code to understand,there is good comments in the source code. But still had tough time to understand, may be my knowledge is not upto that mark. However , if anybody has any blog or article that can answer this question. it will be great !!!

Comment: What do you mean by "StreamWriter source code is Unmanaged code"? Are you asking why it is Disposable?

Comment: Just because a type implements `IDisposable` doesn't mean it **must** use unmanaged resources.

Comment: Well, the simplest answer is that it's a subclass of `TextWriter` which is itself disposable.

Comment: You need to edit this question to clarify "unmanaged".  I think you don't know what it means.

Comment: need to know the reason for have dispose method .

Comment: Well @rory.ap unmanaged code is one which is not managed by CLR.

Comment: Dispose is used for cleaning up.  Why do you need to know the reason?

Comment: Why don't you look at its [implementation of Dispose](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f922405b11eca536,references)? It essentially flushes the stream and possibly closes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamWriter` is not an unmanged resource, its a .NET class, and it is 100% managed.

Another totally different thing is that `StreamWriter` might internally use unmanaged resources or own an `IDisposable` object that in turn might use an unmanaged resource, or  simply extends a class that implements `IDisposable`.

The latter two are the reasons why `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable`, but beware, implementing `IDisposable` does *not* necessarily mean that the class uses directly or indirectly unmanaged resources.

In the particular case of `StreamWriter`, it is obvious that it might indirectly consume unmanged resources; the underlying stream (the `IDisposable` instance field `Stream stream`) could be a `FileStream` which obviously consumes unmanaged resources (a file in your HD for instance). But its also very possible that the underlying stream doesn't use any unmanaged resources, but as [Colin Mackay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079940/can-any-one-explain-why-streamwriter-is-an-unmanaged-resource/39080068#comment65508108_39080068) correctly points out in commentaries below, all streams must implement a consistent interface which the abstract class [`Stream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,f956b0c07e86df64) provides.

Comment: thanks, want to understand what is that streamwriter use that enforce the implementation of IDisposable interface.

Comment: @sameer Two reasons. First and foremost, becuase it derives from `TextWriter` which implements `IDisposable`. Second because it internally uses a `Stream` field which is an `IDisposable` object (one of the reasons I gave where your should implement `Dispose()`).

Comment: Whether the underlying stream is managed or not, it must (as must the streams themselves) still have a consistent interface for any callers otherwise you break the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @ColinMackay Exactly, `Stream` is not unmanaged nor does it use any unmanaged resources. Its simply an ´abstract´ type providing the consistent interface you refer to; wether the concrete underlying stream uses unmanaged resources or not is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamWriter` is managed, but it's a convention that disposing a .NET Stream object will always dispose of any underlying streams.  Streams are often constructed as containers or wrappers around other streams.  For example, the `StreamWriter` might be a wrapper around a `FileStream` (e.g. when you create your `StreamWriter` using `System.IO.File.CreateText`).  Since a `FileStream` uses managed resources, and you don't necessarily have a direct reference to it, it's important to be able to dispose it by calling Dispose() on the `StreamWriter`.

A `FileStream` contains managed resources in the form of OS-level file handles.